# My iterators are not working the way they are supposed to be working

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++14

So this is my code for selection sort and for some reason the part where I swap the two elements it doesn't work and gives all sorts of weird outputs.

```
vector<int> vect{45,32,12,1,67,34,2,15,33,40};
for(auto i=vect.begin();i<vect.end()-1;i++){
    auto min=i;
    for(auto j=i+1;j<vect.end();j++)
    {
        if(*min>*j)
        {
            min=j;
        }
    }
    *i=*i+*min;
    *min=*i-*min;
    *i=*i-*min;
}
for(int x:vect)
{
    cout<<x<<" ";
}
```

But when I use a different way of swapping the output comes out correct.

```
int temp=*min;
*min=*i;
*i=temp;
```

instead of:-

```
*i=*i+*min;
*min=*i-*min;
*i=*i-*min;
```

Please help me find out where it went wrong.

Comment: use `std::swap`

Comment: If you will say "I can't use std::swap", then at the very least, create a function that swaps two values.  Your swaps are hard to read as-is, with all of the dereferencing going on.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I totally understand that using std::swap is the best way or making a function but I could have done that on my own. I want to know what went wrong with my swapping. Thanks.

Comment: *but I could have done that on my own* -- Isn't that the goal, to be able to do something on your own, or better yet, best practices?  It doesn't win points by implementing code that is almost unreadable and unreliable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie mate like I said I am familiar with std::swap but I am new to iterators and in an attempt to achieve a command over them I am implementing all the standard algorithms with iterators hence the way the code looks. But anyway thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to C++!

Your main problem here is that there are case when iterator `i` points the same object as iterator `min`.

What you will really get is

```cpp
    *i=*i+*i;
    *i=*i-*i;
    *i=*i-*i;
```

Hence you will get a zero result!

In order to fix that you must not swap when iterators are equal.

```cpp
vector<int> vect{45,32,12,1,67,34,2,15,33,40};
for(auto i=vect.begin();i<vect.end()-1;i++){
    auto min=i;
    for(auto j=i+1;j<vect.end();j++)
    {
        if(*min>*j)
        {
            min=j;
        }
    }
    if (i==min) continue; // ADD THIS
    *i=*i+*min;
    *min=*i-*min;
    *i=*i-*min;
}
for(int x:vect)
{
    cout<<x<<" ";
}
```

Best Regards!

Comment: Whilst this corrects the code its frankly unreadable and slower to do the "magic" swap. `std::swap` is just much better.

Answer (score 1):

You always need a temp variable to swap two elements. It's exactly like you want to swap two cups, you'd need a third.

Comment: Really? I had the impression that a=a+b; b=a-b; a=a-b swaps a and b succesfully.

Comment: @astormofswords it fails if `a` is an alias for `b`